# Playing RTSP mrl in Android using VideoView

Tags: java, android

I have try to play a RTSP link but unable to play in Android using 
Video View . Also tried to stream using media Player.None to them work but Its streaming smoothly in iOS.

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(liveURI));
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
```

Comment: do you have any error log ? please include those in the question ,so we can figure out easily

Comment: Error Log : 

 E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
 E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
D/VideoView: Error: 1,-2147483648
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@1ea8520
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@c2a9ed9
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@dc2d34c
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@11d4f95
finally i get a message
Can`t play this video.

Answer (score 0):

```
String  videoRtspUrl=“rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov“;

private void playInVideoView() {
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        videoView.setVideoPath(videoRtspUrl);
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
}

private void playInApp(){
if (videoRtspUrl.startsWith("rtsp://")) {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoRtspUrl));
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Also check for the Internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4

please play this , not working for me .

Comment: It is test url, u need to replace with your running RTSP url.

Comment: I am getting this error log========
 E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
 E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
 E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails
 E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
Couldn't open rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: rtsp://mpv.cdn3.bigCDN.com:554/bigCDN/mp4:bigbuckbunnyiphone_400.mp4

Comment: Thanks Its working for the url you provided.But Not working for me as when streaming my IP camera.

Comment: Check if the mobile device and camera are accessed and in a same network.

Comment: they are not on the same network. Its working fine in iOS.Live Streaming is working fine over same network.